# How to solve 'Syntax Error: Unexpected token' when starting cypress-cucumber tests

Tags: node.js, automation, cucumber, cypress

I am running a cucumber based test suite using cypress on both my local environment(Using windows 10) and on gitlab CI/CD pipeline and the tests do not get to start because the runner throws the error below
[image: Cypress local runner]

[image: Cypress gitlab runner]

I have done research and most answers that were closely related to this(but not similar) suggested updating all my dependencies, and trying different versions of node, which I did but still cannot figure out. I have also checked through my test files and there is no syntax error, I am also not sure where to check for the `S.<anonymous>` file.